# Get page content with theme structure in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm working on an ajax-based Wordpress site and I want to know if there is a way to get a particular page content **with** theme structure applied in.

One workaround is to use

> wget

or

> file_get_contents(page_url)

but it'd be cleaner to use Wordpress built-in functions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with `file_get_contents`. I'm not aware of a built-in WP function to do this, but even if there was one I would expect it to be based on `file_get_contents`

Answer (score 0):

FYI, don't use any of these methods I mentioned above because it's way too slow. I ended up utilizing the Loop and `include_once();` to get the content with the theme structure.